# 1us delay in STM32

Tags: assembly, timer, stm32

I want to generate 1us Timer interrupt in STM32F103 blue pill using TIM2 as Timebase unit.(CPU at 32Mhz)

these are the formula and understanding which I get to know after reading datasheets and articles so as to calculate the amount of time delay we can create by one single transition of the counter from 0->1->2->3 and so on.

[The formula for calculating Timer delay of 1us](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Om6AB.png)

[for making timer2 run with 1us time period](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEwSI.png)

and these are the functions that I created further
[timer delay functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDPbJ.png)

but on evaluating this toggling of pin PC13 on the analyzer it shows the delay of 2us
[logic analyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHaFy.png)

because of which when I make a delay of 1 sec, it also gets increased.

I am not able to get why is this happening, checked my formula a hundred times, register values but can't get where am I wrong.

are my formula and logic correct????? or is there any fault in my code??????. where exactly is the problem. i just want to generate the 1us delay on each Update event.

will be waiting for valuable suggestions

Comment: Please add codes into your question text, instead of giving image links.

Comment: so you set the timer for 1us and you are getting a state change every 1us?  which is a period of 2us?  when you set the timer to 0.5us what did you see?

Comment: is there a divide by 2 somewhere upstream in the clock tree that you didnt account for?  I would expect the timer to state change on a timeout not magically figure out what the half timeout is.  when you post your code maybe we can look at it.

Comment: Generating 1us interrupt using max 72MHz uC is not a good idea (it is rather a very bad idea).